# Get element inside element by class - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname

How can i get first or last `<p>` element in Class by classname?no jQuery

```
<div class ="demo">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some other text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].children[0]` should return the first `<p>..</p>`

Comment: `document.querySelector(".demo p:first-child")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

```js
var firstChild = document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].children[0];
console.log(firstChild)
```

```html
<div class ="demo">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some other text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.demo')
console.log(ele.firstElementChild)//first element of class
console.log(ele.lastElementChild)//last element of class
```

```html
<div class ="demo">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some other text</p>
</div>
```